# Vue js. access axios in get function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, axios

im trying to get access to the axios instance in this little api client im making. how can i acheive that? What i want to do is to be able to call axios in getUsers.

```
import axios from 'axios'

/*export const API = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/'  
})*/

let getReq = new Request('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', {
  method: 'GET',
  header: new Headers()
})

export default class Api {
  static getUsers () {
    const request = getReq
    return axios.get()
      .then(response => response.json())
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an axios instance. In your case, it's `API`. Uncomment the `API` definition block, remove the export directive, and use it:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const API = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/'  
})

export default class Api {
  static getUsers () {

    API.get('users/')
      .then(response => {/*do something with response.data here*/})
  }
}
```

Comment: What about if i want to call getUsers() from another file?

Comment: Put that function in another file, say, `api.js`: export { getUsers() {...} }, then import in from your file: `import {getUsers} from 'api';`